# fluentd output is empty on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: fluentd

I am new to fluentd.
My question is why I do not see my outputfile in /var/log/fluentd/mail?
Here is my simple config

```
  <source>
    @type tail
    @id input_tail_mail
    tag mail
    <parse>
      @type none
    </parse>
    path /var/log/mail.log
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/mail.pos
  </source>
  
  <match mail>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluent/mail
  </match>
```

There is no errors in the fluentd logs. All directories/files are created with proper permissions. No fancy extended file attributes.

I guess the issue with the tag but I cannot figure out what is the `tag` value after it leaves the `<source>`.

Is there a way to dump all the tags from running system?

Comment: Did you test with `stdout`?

Comment: @Azeem yes, it works fine with that

Comment: Please add the startup logs to your question. Also, run Fluentd with `--dry-run` and `-v`/`-vv` flag.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem. I start fluentd via `systemctl restart td-agent` - how do I do dry-run or add -v params pls?

Comment: One way to do it to stop the service and manually run it from the command-line to debug this issue. Please refer to the documentation: https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/trouble-shooting